# dev.off() function is deleting the content of my plot

Tags: r, plot, png

I am trying to save my plot as a png to my working directory. I can see it save, but then when I try to use the dev.off() function the content of my plot disappears in my saved folder. If I don't use the dev.off() then when I go to run more script changes occur to my saved plot. How do I save my heat map as a png? Here is an example of my code

```
#Create Heat Map
TalusSouthHeatMap <- wtr.heat.map(TalusSouthdf)
TalusSouthHeatMap

#Save Plot
getwd()
setwd("/Users/heathershaw/Desktop/DepthProfiles2023/TalusSouthHeatMaps")
png(file = "TalusSouthHeatMap.png",
width = 500, height = 500)

plot (TalusSouthHeatMap <- wtr.heat.map(TalusSouthdf))

dev.off()
```

Comment: Can't you just replace the line `plot (TalusSouthHeatMap <- wtr.heat.map(TalusSouthdf))` with `wtr.heat.map(TalusSouthdf)`?

Comment: `wtr.heat.map` doesn't appear to use grid graphics. I don't believe it returns anything, it only plots. Follow Allan's advice.